# Restoring messages from backup not working

Tags: macos

I tried restoring the folder `~/Library/Messages`, and `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat`, but when I opened Messages every single Message but the last was gone for every conservation. Can I bring back my Messages somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages themselves are stored in the database file, `~/Library/Messages/chat.db`. After that file is definitely in place, try rebooting your computer.

In my case, once that file was in place it would only show 1 message from each of the conversations, but after rebooting, all of the messages showed up.

Comment: Also, it would be good to know, what OS version are you using?